# regex pattern not fit well for code like assignment

Tags: regex

i am trying to use a regular expression to match expression like code assignment
for example:

```
"k=++g677"
"k=--j77"
"k=++gfrf677frfr"
```

i've tried:

```
([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]|\d)*[=][+][+]|[-][-]|[*][*]|[\/][\/]([\d]*|([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]\d)*))
```

but it's seemds to match also things like

```
"k++"
"k=++@ff"
```

can u help?

Comment: Only the first branch of your regex requires a `=` to match. The other alternatives match just `--` or `**`, etc.

Comment: Is `k=++a--b` valid?

Comment: See my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56372987/3832970) with 2  solutions: with captured parts and without. Please add comments / edit the question here or below the answer if you need any more help.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z_][\da-zA-Z_]*=([+*\/-])\1[a-zA-Z_][\da-zA-Z_]*$
```

Or, if you need to capture each detail into a separate group:

```
^([a-zA-Z_][\da-zA-Z_]*)(=)(([+*\/-])\4)([a-zA-Z_][\da-zA-Z_]*)$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3GmlVh/6) and [its graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%5Ba-zA-Z%5Cd%5D*%3D(%5B%2B*%5C%2F-%5D)%5C1%5Ba-zA-Z%5Cd%5D%2B%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z_]` - an uppercase ASCII letter or underscore
- `[a-zA-Z\d_]*`  - 0 or more alphanumerics / `_` (replace with `\w` if it is not Unicode aware by default)
- `=` - an equal sign
- `([+*\/-])\1` - `+`, `*`, `/` or `-` and then exactly 1 the same char
- `[a-zA-Z_]` - an ASCII letter or `_`
- `[a-zA-Z\d_]*` - 0 or more alphanumerics / `_` (replace with `\w` if it is not Unicode aware by default)
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression: `([a-zA-Z_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_])*)\s*=\s*(\d+|(\+\+|--|\*\*|//)?((?:[a-zA-Z_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_])*))|(?:[a-zA-Z_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_])*)(\+\+|--))$`

It is long because of its last part, so it will match for `k = x++` too.

One problem was that you forgot to use some parenthesis. Use them everywhere, in that way you can make sure that nothing happens unintentionally.

`[\d]*` matches nothing, `[\d]+` is what you shall use.

**Note:** A variable name can contain the `_` character.

[See explanation on regex101...](https://regex101.com/r/T8jRie/1)

Comment: *A contrario* I'd say avoid using useless parenthesis, they make regex unreadable. Why are you adding `_`, it is not present in OP? and `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_])*` is better written as `\w*`

Comment: Correct functionality is more important than readability. Usually when I have to create a longer regular expression, I split them into variables to make them readable.
Also \w will match to other non ASCII characters too, like korean, chinese, etc.